# Leaflet.draw - Fire an event when edition of a circle or polygon ends?

Tags: events, leaflet, shapes, leaflet.draw

I'm using [Leaflet.draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) v[1.0.3](https://unpkg.com/leaflet-draw@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.draw.js)

Here is my basic scenario :

I load all shapes (only polygons or circles) created previously by the user from my DB.
These shapes are editable.

However, I can't find an `Edited` or `EditedComplete` event, fired when edit **ends**. My goal is to get the new coordinates (radius and center if it's a circle, or lat/lng of every polygon's vertex) and store them in my DB.
Obviously, I need only one update operation, when edit process is over.

I've only found :

- `L.Draw.Event.EDITRESIZE` but it's fired during the resize process, not when it's over.
- `L.Draw.Event.EDITMOVE` but it's fired during the move process, not when it's over.

The event `L.Draw.Event.EDITED` exists but it doesn't fire when expected.

I guess these events exist, but I can't find them. I've only found [this issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/664), and it worries me...
Any help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I met the same issue and I fixed it by doing the following :

after creating the layer (circle / polygone ) , I added an edit listener on the created layer :

```
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function(e) {
    var type = e.layerType
    , layer = e.layer;
    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);       
    layer.on("edit", function(event) {
        console.log("layer edited !");
        ..........
    });
});
```

You can take a look at this example :

http://jsfiddle.net/Zoubir/oer03zu4/
In order to check : Create a polygone or circle and pass to edit mode , update a radius and see

I hope this can Help